# Add file to MSI binary table using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I want to add a custom action that calls a VBScript from the binary table using powershell.
I have searched everywhere to find powershell code to do this it all seems to be VBScript. I have tried to do it myself but it always errors.
Has anyone been able to add a file to the binary table with powershell?
Would really appreciate any help.
Here is what I have so far:
Here is the code I have so far: 
VBScript

```
Dim query
query="INSERT INTO `Binary` (`Name`, `Data`) VALUES ('NewBlob', ?)"
Set Installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

Set Record = Installer.CreateRecord(1)
Record.SetStream 1, "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\coder\CA_Test.vbs"

Set Database = Installer.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\7z920.msi", 1)

Set View = Database.OpenView(query)
View.Execute Record
Database.Commit
```

Powershell

```
$windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer             
$database1 = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "OpenDatabase", 
    "InvokeMethod", 
    $Null, 
    $windowsInstaller, 
    @($database1Path, $msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly)
)  

$database2 = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "OpenDatabase", 
    "InvokeMethod", 
    $Null, 
    $windowsInstaller, 
    @($database2Path, $msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact)
) 
$query = "INSERT INTO ``Binary``(``Name``,``Data``) VALUES    ('Callsetstatuskey', ?)"
$View = $database2.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "OpenView",
    "InvokeMethod",
    $Null,
    $database2,
    ($query)
 )

$Record = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember  ("CreateRecord", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $windowsInstaller, 1)
$Record.GetType().InvokeMember("SetStream", "InvokeMethod", $Null,  $windowsInstaller.Record, @($SetstausKeyPath, 1))

$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Record)      
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($View) | Out-Null
```

There is a lot more code in the powershell script create features, components add registry keys properties and custom actions. Everything works great except for adding the file in the binary table.

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim, i think I've answered your question here: http://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/2017/02/10/write-windows-installer-binary-stream-using-powershell/

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `Binary` (`Name`,`Data`) Values(?,?)"
$View = $database2.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView","InvokeMethod",$Null,$database2,($query))
$binaryrecord = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("CreateRecord", "InvokeMethod", $null, $windowsInstaller, 2)  
$binaryrecord.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", "SetProperty", $null, $binaryrecord, @(1, "AlkaneBinary"))
$fileToStream = "C:\Alkane\AlkaneFile.txt"
$binaryrecord.GetType().InvokeMember("SetStream","InvokeMethod", $null, $binaryrecord, @(2, $fileToStream))
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $binaryrecord)
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($View) | Out-Null
```

Thanks.